# Laravel 5.4 API not returning JSON in Postman

Tags: laravel, api, postman

I've Created a new Laravel 5.4 Project, Created the model ' Recipe ' , the migrations table ' recipes ' and added the routes to the ' Api.php ' . But when testing my API in Postman, instead of getting a Json Response i get a Html File.

Here are the codes as per the below files:

API.php Routes file

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Route::post('/recipe', 'RecipeController@postRecipe')-
>name('get_recipe');
Route::get('/recipe', 'RecipeController@getRecipe')-
>name('post_recipe');
```

RecipeController

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use App\Recipe;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class RecipeController extends Controller {

public function postRecipe(Request $request)
{
    $recipe = new Recipe();
    $recipe->content = $request->input('content');
    $recipe->save();
    return response()->json(['recipe' => $recipe], 201);
}

public function getRecipe()
{
    return response()->json(['message' => 'Got a Response'],200);
}
```

Recipe Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Recipe extends Model
{
protected $fillable = ['content'];
}
```

The migration was migrated and the table ' recipes '  created ' .

Then in postman i try a ' get ' request to my url: ' recipeapi.dev/api/recipe ' but get html codes.

The same happens when i try a ' post ' request to my url: ' recipeapi.dev/api/recipe ' . OFC for the post request i include headers: ' Content-Type ' ' application/json ' . Still getting the same html codes....

Using Homestead/vagrant for laravel and if i use browser to go to default route: '/' it brings me to the welcome Laravel Page.

Don't know whats the problem i keep getting these html codes and not Json Data as per my controller.

Here are the pics of postman with the data....

[Get request with Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngDac.jpg)

[Post request with Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgtRm.png)

Anyone got any idea what's going on? Why are my not getting Json data from my api from the get and post request?

Thanks Guys!

Comment: Click on the Preview button to see if you have errors.

Comment: @tompec This is what i get in postman preview:

Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

1/1
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
in RouteCollection.php line 161
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 821
at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 691
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 675............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appreciate all your help! You guys are very kind to take time away from your busy schedules.

I finally solved this issue. I feel very silly now. I just had to do a vagrant command ' vagrant provision ' in the homestead directory since i'm using Homestead, and all was working.

I seem to get this issue from time to time especially when i create Authorisations ' php artisan make:auth ' , in which i would thereafter have to make a vagrant provision command in order for the login, register parts ect.. of authorisations to show up on webpages.

Don't know what's the cause of this issue, but problem solved.

Thanks again Guys! Appreciate it!

Answer (score 4):

You should just add these two headers to your request:

```
Accept: application/json

Content-type: application/json
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it dosen't even find the route.

Please replace your `api.php` file by this and retry a `GET` request:

```
<?php

Route::get('recipe', 'RecipeController@getRecipe')->name('get_recipe');
Route::post('recipe', 'RecipeController@postRecipe')->name('post_recipe');
```

Comment: I tried the suggestion but still no luck. Still same html file. Very strange why its not working. I'm just curious as to whether there is a setting in laravel to make api's work? Maybe i'm missing something in order to test an API? Basically create the routes in api route file e.g a ' get ', return json data e.g. returning a message to test. Test in postman. Are my missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

You should turn off Laravel Debugbar when testing API. Or you can just turn it off for all API routes.

Here's a solution for Laravel 5 from [here](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar/issues/252):

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;

class ProfileJsonResponse
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);

        if (
            $response instanceof JsonResponse &&
            app()->bound('debugbar') &&
            app('debugbar')->isEnabled() &&
            is_object($response->getData())
        ) {
            $response->setData($response->getData(true) + [
                '_debugbar' => app('debugbar')->getData(),
            ]);
        }

        return $response;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've created a middleware named ProfileJsonResponse, pasted in your code, registered it in kernel.php as 'pjr' => \App\Http\Middleware\ProfileJsonResponse::class, used it in my api routes but still postman returns html page. My Api routes look like this: 
Route::group(['middleware' => 'pjr'], function () {
    Route::post('/recipe', 'RecipeController@postRecipe')->name('get_recipe');
    Route::get('/recipe', 'RecipeController@getRecipe')->name('post_recipe');
});

Comment: @JohnBiggs first, try to disable debugbar. If you see JSON after disabling it, try to fix this by using middleware. I didn't use this middleware, that's why I gave you a link in my answer. Read it, I'm pretty sure there are answers to all questions there.

Answer (score 0):

The http status returned is a 404.

The body of the response appears to be an HTML page (404 Error page?)

The server doesn't recognize the URL.

I would check to make sure you are using the correct URL.

Comment: Hmm it is a html page. But my routes are in API.php route file, and as per my controller i am not returning any views. Using browser and going to my URL: recipeapi.dev i get the normal Laravel welcome page which is defined in the normal webroutes. I'm using same URL to access api except that i add api/recipe to the end ie: ' recipeapi.dev/api/recipe ' .

Preview in postman i get: 

This is what i get in postman preview: Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found. 1/1 NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161